# Should i cache the whole query in php or should i just cache the primary key of the row?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

The question is quite straightforward. I can't choose between either. In the dev documents MySQL has specified that indexes can pick a row from it's position rather than searching the whole table.
Suppost i have a request to fetch the 20 best posts in my `Posts` table based on the ratings. Should i just cache the `id`'s of the retrieved Posts or Should i cache the whole results for responding further requests.

Btw i'm using file based caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is cheap and caching 20 rows usually don't take up much.

I would say: Cache the full rows if it isn't data that have a requirement to be fresh.

Comment: but i'm using File Based Caching.

Comment: Then you need to weight if database connections or disk reads on the application server is your main concern.

I would recommend that you implement some sort of in memory cache.

Disk read is probably still faster than accessing the data from the database though.

Comment: I would definitely chose one db call now to 20 individual db calls later. It sounds a little early to be worrying about performance. If it becomes a problem you just change it.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of caching - cache data which has high probability of usage.  In this case the probability is high so do cache them !